# What is the reason for having more than one login link for Facebook?

Tags: login, hyperlinks, facebook

If you do a Google search for facebook you'll see something that I think is rather curious, basically there are two different links, one to log into your account and the other to login to your account.

[image]

The Log in to Facebook link has this URL: https://www.facebook.com/login/
It also has Log in to Facebook as the tab description, and Log In as the dialog title.

And the Login to Facebook link has this URL: https://en-gb.facebook.com/login/
But it has the same Log in to Facebook as the tab description, and Log In as the dialog title.

What is the logical (or perhaps illogical) reason for this?

Comment: If someone has a choice to sign in to a regular Facebook account and a en-fb.Facebook, does this mean they have 2 different Facebook accounts?

Answer (score 4):

One hit is for the American version of the log in page (www.facebook.com), the other is for the UK version of the log in page (en-gb.facebook.com). Possibly these are the only two English versions they provide. All the other (many) localized login pages, such as Swedish (sv-se.facebook.com), french (fr-fr.facebook.com), etc are filtered by Google because it only wants to give you English hits.

I'm in Sweden - in addition to the US and the UK login page, Google includes the Swedish login page.

Comment: This is a correct answer. It should be noted that the reason for rendering two distinct pages is l10n or localization. Although the en_US locale and the en_UK locale are essentially English, there are slight ortographic and grammatical nuances that make a British English speaking user feel more at home in his own locale. remember "I say tomato, you say tomatoe? Apparently Brits log in to Facebook while Americans login to Facebook. Never argue which is correct, the right answer depends on where you are (locale) and wars have been waged over simpler arguments =)

Comment: "two countries separated by a common language" (attributed to George Barnard Shaw)

Answer (score 2):

I would wager that this is non-intentional. My largest indicator that it is non-intentional is the descriptions are the exact same, and if there was meant to be a difference in the two, the descriptions would be different. The second URL with en-gb.facebook.com is a 'top level domain' for the United Kingdom. I am in the United States and just tested to see that indeed there are two links.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.gb